# EF and Code First Migrations with MySQL - dbo.tablename does not exist

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have set up entity framework to use MySQL and created a migration.

When I run update-database I get error "table dbname.dbo.tablename' does not exist. Running in -Verbose mode I see the statement that causes the error :

```
alter table `dbo.Comments` drop foreign key `FK_dbo.Comments_dbo.Comments_Comment_ID`
```

When I run the query direct in MySQL workbench is throws the same error.

The problem seems to be the dbo. prefix in the migration set. Anything in the form dbo.tablename won't run saying that table does not exist. E.g. select * from  dbo.tablename fails but select * from tablename works. The database was generated by Entity Framework and the code first migrations were generated by EF too.

However the migrations generate everything with the dbo. prefix, which does not work.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Outside of migrations, is using Entity Framework with MySql working for your project?

Comment: The strange thing is that migrations also worked initially. But then they stopped working due to dbo. prefix. I still don't get how they worked before.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was having this problem just today as well; found my answer here:
[MySqlMigrationCodeGenerator](https://github.com/pdonald/mysql-connector-net/blob/master/Source/MySql.Data.Entity/MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator.cs)

You have to set:

```
CodeGenerator = new MySqlMigrationCodeGenerator();
```

In your context's configuration class. This will get rid of the schema gibberish for MySQL. My Configuration class looks like this:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<YourContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());
        SetHistoryContextFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", (conn, schema) => new MySqlHistoryContext(conn, schema));
        CodeGenerator = new MySqlMigrationCodeGenerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a solution, but I am unable to build this class, I am getting one error in line string type = MySqlProviderServices.Instance.GetColumnType(typeUsage);  - Instance is not a member of MySqlProviderServices. Any idea?

Comment: I had a look at MySqlProviderServices (from http://bugs.mysql.com/file.php?id=17436&bug_id=62185) and Instance is declared as "internal":   internal static readonly MySqlProviderServices Instance;

Comment: OK I figured it out. You pointed me on the right track. Implementing  the MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator (one that did not build for me) does not seem to be necessary however. In my scenario it's enough to use the overriden MySqlMigrationCodeGenerator and just use the stock MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator class.

Comment: Sorry mate, what I meant was that I found the answer looking at the source code and the MySQL assemblies carry it in stock. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

I have this same issue and I applied the solution posted by Sorio and It generated a lot of problems.

```
CodeGenerator = new MySqlMigrationCodeGenerator();
```

This code line can change all the sql that you generate, for example in my case in the sql code to apply to the database all the foreign key constraints disappear.

I am still without a solution because for me this is not acceptable and I recommend you to check the sql generate with the command before use this solution:

```
update-database -script
```